# QGIS change zones in a raster to grayscale by polygon overlay

Tags: qgis, raster

I've got a raster ortophoto and a polygon layer:

[image]

I need to alter the raster layer as follows:

- Everything that is inside the polygon (overlaying) should stay as it is right now (in color).
- The rest of the raster image (the zone that is not overlaying the polygon) should be changed to grayscale.

I can't imagine right now how to achieve this..

Comment: Do you need it to be a single raster layer? Otherwise, you could use the **clipper** tool to create another raster based inside the polygon. Set the colour for this raster and use a greyscale colour for the overall raster (the one shown in your question) and set the layer ordering so that the new raster is on top.

Comment: Yes, it should be in a single raster...